# Mass, density, and forces on a floating ball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

If I have two balls, one completely in the water (mass = 4m), and the other half submerged (mass = m), the volume of both balls is V = 15 cm^3. They are tied together with a string. How can I calculate the mass of each ball, the density of each ball, and the forces acting upon each ball? Thanks

[image]